# How to delete records in a table with JSON

Tags: php, sql, json

I have a JSON file that brings data in to iOS. I also want it to see if there are more than 2 records.

If there is more than 2 records i want it to delete everything apart from the last 2 records

How do I insert this in to this php file

```
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if(!$dbconnect)
    {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

        $records = array();

        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
            $records[] = $r;        
        }

        //Output the data as JSON
        echo json_encode($records);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using LIMIT 1 which will mean you only get 1 record back. Are you planning on increasing the limit?

You could always use the PHP count() function and the array_slice() function if you need to cull down an array of records returned...

http://php.net/array_slice

Comment: yes that limit is just for one function i need the other value for something else. i need to delete the records as once they are used they wont be used again. so i need something like if record > 2 then delete everything apart from last 2. id there a line of code to do this